# collecting keyvalues from remote json using getJSON

Tags: javascript, sql, json

I'm not very familiar with javascript I hope you can tell me how fix this. I have the the DB table as output in json format, this is a sample:

[{"ID":"11","nombre":"Sapo","direccion":"Chile 11","telefono":"4270044","apertura":"09:00:00","cerradura":"20:00:00","Hint":"sanguche","votos":"3","calificacion":"6.00","actualizacion":"2014-09-15 21:59:43"},{"ID":"12","nombre":"OtroComp","direccion":"San Martin 22","telefono":"456789","apertura":"10:00:00","cerradura":"20:00:00","Hint":"papa al horno y pollo","votos":"2","calificacion":"4.00","actualizacion":"2014-09-15 21:42:01"}]

and this is my code in javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var gclaData = 'http://blablabla.com/jsonpuller.php?callback=?';
$.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
event = 'Next Event Dates<br><br>';

$.each(data.ID, function(j,ID ){

    event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
    event += '<div class="eventID">'+ data.ID +"</div>";
    event += '</div>';
    event +='<hr>';
});
$('#output').html(event);
});
</script>
```

And nothing is shown in the page :-(   how can I display all the ID's ?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change part of the `$.each` with this;

```
$.each(data, function(key){
    event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
    event += '<div class="eventID">'+ data[key].ID +"</div>";
    event += '</div>';
    event +='<hr>';
});
```

Comment: I've realized I have more serious problem, my server doesn't support jsonp, so the data in json array can't be read. The details of the server is [here][1], so what can I do? If I delete the callback in the url, then appears problems in cross domain (damn)
1:http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/phpinfo-default_variables.html

Comment: Try with some other methods, read about it on this blog. Hope it helps. http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html#postm

Comment: I've solve my own problem after reading a lot of this issue, the solution is super simple :D  just put header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")  in the php code. I've tested my code above (with some changes in the output of php) and now it is ok ;-)